# About reshape functions and gluperspective function

Tags: opengl, glut

I am newbie in OpenGL. I read simple codes. I have three questions.

1-) Why does gluperspective function used in reshape function?

2-) What does reshape functions really do? When I run the programs with reshape function and without it nothing really change.

3) When does reshape functions called? If it is only called when we change size of the window, it means if I don't change the size of the window, reshape function won't called so the gluperspective won't called. But doesn't gluperspective need to be called at least once?

Sorry for bad English, and dumb questions.

Comment: Is there some code you're talking about? Because OpenGL doesn't have "reshape functions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1-) Why does gluperspective function used in reshape function?

Because such code is usually written by morons who don't understand OpenGL. Setting matrices (all of them) belongs into the drawing code.

> 2-) What does reshape functions really do? When I run the programs with reshape function and without it nothing really change.

The correct use of the reshape function is to perform one-time operations that need to be done when the window size changes. For example reinitializing textures used as targets in post processing FBOs or such. If you're just drawing a triangle to the screen you don't need a reshape handler.

> 3) When does reshape functions called? If it is only called when we change size of the window, (…)

It's also called when the window is created, as this effectively resizes the window from nothing into some rect.

> it means if I don't change the size of the window, reshape function won't called so the gluperspective won't called.

Creating a new window also (re)sizes it.

> But doesn't gluperspective need to be called at least once?

If your desire is a gluPerspective projection, then yes. Technically what you must do is setting some projection transform, which may also be an identity.

But do not set it in the reshape handler. Doing this belongs into drawing code.

> and dumb questions

Actually those are very good questions. They show that you actually think about code. I wish more people did this :) Keep it up.